# Failed to delete snapshot. snap-0a55ef2a57ce45e17: The snapshot snap-0a55ef2a57ce45e17 is currently in use by ami-0de0d1c34cd7d29d5

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops, amazon-ami

I have deleted the instance, volume, security groups, AMIs and left the snapshots last, now it does not allow me to delete I get this error, help I want to delete it
Failed to delete snapshot.
snap-0a55ef2a57ce45e17: The snapshot snap-0a55ef2a57ce45e17 is currently in use by ami-0de0d1c34cd7d29d5

I was looking for options where I can recover that AMI and nothing